# Why woo-commerce single product page URL ending with page number?

Tags: url, woocommerce

Anyone know why woocommerce single product page end with page number? and page title showing product name then after page 3?

Eg: https://luxurysouq.com/product/millenary-automatic-ladies/3

currently, the page is working fine but this URL is showing in Google search Console Structured Data with ending number.

from the dashboard, the product was saved without number 3.
eg: https://luxurysouq.com/product/millenary-automatic-ladies/

but URL showing a number. supposed to be page redirect to 404 or without number.

Comment: Maybe you are using the `<!--nextpage-->` tag in the content of the post?

Comment: I don't think so, there aren't additional tags in content.